# How to find the row with less amount of entries in a dataset table by foreign key?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In the following schema how could anyone retrieve the `description` that contains the least amount of `feedbacks` using Spring Data JPA?

[image]

I've just tried (based on JPA [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods)):

```java
public interface FeedbackRepository extends JpaRepository<Feedback,Integer> {
    List<Description> countByProductIdOrderByDescriptionId();
}
```

however, this approach was unsuccessful.

The complete project can be found on this [Github repository](https://github.com/celsofranssa/Feedback-API).

Comment: Just count the number of feedback records grouped by description id then sort on the count.

Comment: @Erik, could you provide a code snippet?

Comment: I never use JPA, I prefer plain old SQL qeuries. That would be something like: `SELECT min(count(id)) FROM feedback GROUP BY description_id;` Maybe there's an annotation somewhere that let's you just specify the query.